# Error while loading shared libraries libqgis_core.2.9.0

Tags: qgis

I have complied QGIS version 2.8.1 from source, according to the instructions from https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL

Now after successfully running ccmake .., make and make install commands and I move the install directory, I get the following error in terminal, when executing the generated binaries

`./qgis`

`./qgis: error while loading shared libraries: libqgis_core.so.2.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Any thoughts?

**Edit**
**What worked:**

After some search on the internet I found the following procedure that works permanently

`~$ cd {path}/lib/     # change directory to qgis installed app lib directory {}
lib\$ pwd > qqis.2.8.conf  # get current working directory and paste to a file
lib\$ sudo mv qqis.2.8.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d
lib\$ sudo ldconfig`

Now compiled qgis installed at a custom location, will load all the time `./qgis` is executed

Comment: Did you follow the part of the instructions that said: 'If you get the error message "error while loading shared libraries", execute this command in your shell.  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${HOME}/apps/lib/`'

Comment: Sorry I overlooked it, I thought it refereed to a different error. But having executed it in terminal. I still get the error as before.

Comment: This is what `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` shows `:/usr/local/grass-7.1.svn//lib:/home/appz/qgis-2.8/lib/` and I still get an error. Is this solution permanent? Because I think after closing the terminal the variable will disappear